# How to print a 2D list in one line?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print a 2-dimensional array on a single output line (without `\n`).

The closest I've got is to this output

```
[28098, 24390, 15876] [8352, 12876, 12644]
```

using

```
print(*result)
```

I'd like to remove the commas (substitute them with spaces) and remove the brackets.

Comment: `print(str([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]).replace(',', ''))` outputs `[[1 2 3] [3 4 5]]` which may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Is your expected output `8098, 24390, 15876, 8352, 12876, 12644`? Note the comma between 15876 and 8352.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it in straightforward way

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
res = [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist] # flatten array
print(" ".join(map(str, res))) # convert all array elements to str and concatenate them
1 2 3 3 4 5
```

Or you could use `itertools`

```
import itertools
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
res = list(itertools.chain(*arr))
print(" ".join(map(str, res)))
1 2 3 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lest=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
i=0
while(i<len(lest)):
    interArrylength=len(lest[i])
    k=0
    while(k<interArrylength):
        print(lest[i][k],end=" ")
        k=k+1
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
result = ""
for sublist in list:
    for element in sublist:
           result += str(element)
print(result)
```

123456789

Comment: This question already has two answers (accepted and another). Given those two answers the expected output should have a space between the elements as in `1 2 3 ...`. In any case, it'd better to also explain why this solution is a better approach than the already existing answers; especially since this is an old question which is already answered. Also refer to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
nd_a = np.array(a)

for arr in nd_a:
    for element in arr:
        print(element,end=" ")
        print(" ",end=" ")
```