# How to print a 2D matrix as a one-line string?

Tags: python

How would one take a matrix and convert it to a string with all the values being on one line?

For example:

```
input: [[3,4,1,5],[5,3,2,1]]
output: "34155321"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a 2D list in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752354/how-to-print-a-2d-list-in-one-line)

Comment: I updated your title because it was misleading. There is no dictionary, that's a 2D list or a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one:

```
L = [[3,4,1,5],[5,3,2,1]]
print(''.join([''.join(map(str, L_)) for L_ in L]))
```

**Output:**

```
34155321
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will combine all item from a given list to a String

```
input_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

output = ""

for item in input_list:
    for num in item:
        output += str(num)

print(output)
```

The output of the code:

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your input is not a dicionary but a list.

Solution:

1. flatten your list of lists
2. join the elements of the list

```py
# 1. flatten your list:
def flatten(xs: list):
    for x in xs:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x

# 2. join the list to string
result = "".join(map(str, flatten(input)))
```

The `map(str, x)` takes an iterable x and converts each element in x into a string which is necessary to apply `join()` on x.